# Rails 4, Turbolinks 3, Partial Replacement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

How to use this new Turbolinks 3.0 (branch: 'master') with Rails 4.2?

I'm trying and I got from Chrome this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

If I use partial replacement like this:

```
<%= link_to "Something", root_path %>
```

and then in the same page:

```
<script> Turbolinks.visit(url, { change: 'areaDiv' }); </script>
```

according to docs: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#partial-replacements-with-turbolinks-30

The page is reloaded entirely and I got that error. How to do?

**EDIT THE DAY AFTER**

I have Rails 4.2.1 standard.

In Gemfile I added:

```
gem 'turbolinks', :github => 'rails/turbolinks', :branch => 'master'
```

Now in one controller I have:

```
def ok_category
      render plain: "Ok", change: 'categoriesdiv'
  end
```

or maybe this:

```
 def red_category
      redirect_to "http://www.google.com", change: 'categoriesdiv'
  end
```

or another like this:

```
def red_category
      render partial: 'category_choose', change: 'categoriesdiv'
  end
```

also if I add the `, turbolinks: true` at the end of each line, NOTHING!

My chrome window's title is changing in a laconic "undefined", but if I use the Chrome developer tool it says to me in "Network" tab that the request to the server is complete with "GET" method, "304" status, "Text/Javascript" type, all without errors.

In the application.html.erb I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Hello!</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div id="test"><%= Time.now.to_s %></div>
<div id="links"><%= link_to "Testmylink", ok_category_path(1), remote:true %></div>

<%= yield %>

<div id="categoriesdiv" data-turbolinks-temporary>Yes yes!</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <p class="text-center">Hello!</p>
</footer>
</div>
</body></html>
```

What is wrong with me?

Comment: How does your script get triggered?

Answer (score 1):

Turbolinks is tricky, either way here is a resource worth spending some time on. I see slight syntax differentiation between what you write and how the do.

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/448

Comment: This is an issue on Github. In the Readme (the doc) in home they published the correct version of syntax, that I respect. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When using `link_to` the `remote` parameter tells rails to use turbolinks to follow the link so I think you need `remote: true`.

You also need to add your change area, I'm not certain about that bit but I would go for something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Something", root_path, remote: true, { :change => 'areaDiv' } %>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
...change => 'areaDiv'} );

Comment: There is no round bracket here (unless you changed the code) so look around at your other code (particularly the line before) to see if there's not something else causing that error.

Comment: Now, i'm using onclick: "Turbolinks.visit('root_path', {change: 'areaDiv'} and it works. But, onclick is really the way?

Comment: I hope not, I see that the issue referred to below suggests it though. Have you tried with something like `'data-turbolinks-change' => 'areaDiv'` (or maybe `data: {'turbolinks-change' => 'areaDiv'}`)? (I can't tell whether this is what's being proposed in the issue though)

Comment: Dear @jcuenod, i'm trying. But if you read the docs here (https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#partial-replacements-with-turbolinks-30) what you think we have to do for link_to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77383/discussion-between-john-sam-and-jcuenod).